# Getting ErrorException after installing Laravel spatie/permission

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, laravel-permission

I am trying to install the package `spatie/laravel-permission` to help manage my roles and permissions in an application. I keep running into the following problem. According to the documentation, to install `Laravel permission`, you run this command

```
composer require spatie/laravel-permission
```

However, when I do, I am getting this error:

```
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   ErrorException  : Trying to access array offset on value of type null

  at /home/anto/encomm/projects/vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/PermissionServiceProvider.php:61
    57|     protected function registerModelBindings()
    58|     {
    59|         $config = $this->app->config['permission.models'];
    60| 
  > 61|         $this->app->bind(PermissionContract::class, $config['permission']);
    62|         $this->app->bind(RoleContract::class, $config['role']);
    63|     }
    64| 
    65|     protected function registerBladeExtensions()

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError()
      /home/anto/encomm/projects/vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/PermissionServiceProvider.php:61

  2   Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::registerModelBindings()
      /home/anto/encomm/projects/vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/PermissionServiceProvider.php:36

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

The following are the contents of my `composer.json` file:

```
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/passport": "^8.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.1",
        "owen-it/laravel-auditing": "^9.3",
        "sudiptpa/guid": "^1.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using updated Composer version?

Comment: I ran `composer update` before installation and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some changes on the file `vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/PermissionServiceProvider.php` after run the first `composer require spatie/laravel-permission` statement

This is actual code on line 61/62:

```
$this->app->bind(PermissionContract::class, $config['permission']);
$this->app->bind(PermissionContract::class, $config['role']);
```

Need to be changed with this:

```
$this->app->bind(PermissionContract::class, isset($config['permission']));
$this->app->bind(PermissionContract::class, isset($config['role']));
```

After that change run again `composer require spatie/laravel-permission` and that's all. On newest releases of PHP you must check whether a variable is null or not with [isset():](https://www.php.net/isset)